# How to create a new array based on the existing array with .map() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to see two items in the result but I'm getting them twice, why?

```
    let arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.fill(
      arr.map((item) => item * 10)
    );
```

Comment: I think you should read the docs for [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: Why are you calling `arr.fill()` in the first place? What do you think it does?

Comment: I guess, I see what you mean. The .map() will replace the items in the array and the .fill() method will do the same and that's why I get it twice, right?

Comment: `.map()` doesn't replace anything, it creates a new array with the results of calling the function on each element.

Comment: It's not a great question, not worth upvotes, but I don't know why they downvoted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254754/discussion-between-novigda-and-barmar).

Comment: Please don't recycle your question, especially after they are answered. Now, the comments and the answers don't make any sense. I rollback your last change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr.fill()` replaces each element of the array with its argument. So

```
arr.fill(
  arr.map((item) => item * 10)
);
```

is equivalent to:

```
let temp = arr.map((item) => item * 10);
arr[0] = temp;
arr[1] = temp;
```

So you now have a 2x2 array, where each row of the array is the original array multiplied by 10. When you convert that to a string, you get all 4 items separated by commas.

If you just want the original array multiplied by 10, don't call `arr.fill()`, just assign the result of `arr.map()` to the `innerHTML`.

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.map((item) => item * 10);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```